# child's css interfering with the parent's css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component that is called by the app component, but when you include margin-top in the child component, it interferes with the parent component, causing the parent component to take the margin instead of only the child component getting margin-top

```js
import "../src/App.css";
import CardComponent from "./components/CardComponent";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className="card"></div>
      <CardComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
function CardComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="card-component-wraper">
      <div> FAQs </div>
      <div>
        <div> What is Frontend Mentor, and how will it help me? </div>
        Frontend Mentor offers realistic coding challenges to help developers
        improve their frontend coding skills with projects in HTML, CSS, and
        JavaScript. It's suitable for all levels and ideal for portfolio
        building.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardComponent;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  background-color: hsl(275, 100%, 97%);
  background-image: url("../assets/images/background-pattern-desktop.svg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
.card-component-wraper {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: It's called "margin collapse". There are various fixes, like putting a tiny top padding on the parent, using overflow properties etc.

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the `*` selector. Also, consider closing your app div.

Comment: Likely a culprit of margin collapsing, as @ralph.m suggested. See [this Smashing Magazine article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/margins-in-css/#parent-and-first-or-last-child-element) that covers this topic in depth.

Answer (score -1):

To ensure the margin only affects the CardComponent itself, you can use absolute units (like pixels) or a different approach to apply margin specifically to the child component without impacting the parent. Here's an example:

```
.card-component-wraper {
/* Other styles */
position: relative; /* Important for absolute positioning */
width: 20%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-left: 40%;
```

}

```
.card-component-wraper > div:first-child {
/* Apply margin to the first child div within CardComponent */
margin-top: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
```

}

In this adjusted CSS, the margin-top is applied specifically to the first child div within CardComponent. Adjust the margin value (20px in this example) to suit your layout needs.